# Ransack Sorting Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ransack

I'm a bit new to Rails in general and currently I am trying to get sortable columns working using ransack. A problem I'm running into is getting associated columns to sort. Below is a sample of my code where the Product table is attempting to sort supplier names.

I have tried replacing :supplier_name with 'suppliers.supplier_name' as the README suggested but to no avail.

**Controller**

```
def index
    @search = Product.search(params[:q])
    @products = @search.result.includes(:supplier)
end
```

**Model**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :supplier
end
```

```
class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, inverse_of: :supplier, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Product Index**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= sort_link @search, :product_name, "Name" %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @search, :product_description, "Description" %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @search, :product_cost, "Cost" %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @search, :product_category, "Category" %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @search, :product_status, "Status" %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @search, :date_modified, "Date Modified" %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @search, :supplier_name, "Supplier" %></th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= sanitize product.product_name.html_safe %></td>
        <td><%= sanitize product.product_description.html_safe %></td>
        <td><%= sanitize number_to_currency(product.product_cost).html_safe %></td>
        <td><%= sanitize product.prodcategory.category.html_safe %></td>
        <td><%= sanitize product.prodstatus.status.html_safe %></td>
        <td><%= sanitize product.date_modified.strftime("%B %-d, %Y").html_safe %></td>
        <td><%= sanitize product.supplier.supplier_name.html_safe %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Details', product %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Delete', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I have to name it by association_fieldname. So in this instance it would be

```
 <th><%= sort_link @search, :supplier_supplier_name, "Supplier" %></th>
```